# Which preposition should follow "sympathies"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, prepositional-objects

I want to ask an organization:

> Does your organization have any sympathies __ [such and such ideology (X)].

Which preposition should follow "sympathies?"

I was thinking "to" might work, as if their sympathies are poised in the direction of X.  But "for" could work also, as if they have sympathies stored up and reserved for X.

Please help with this particular instance and also help in how to think through similar instances would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe "toward" if we don't know if the organization has a position one way or the other; or "for" if we want to know which way the organization's position is leaning. // Why don't you just ask for its positions (regarding whatever topics you're interested in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider ***towards***, instead. Or [*toward* in US](http://blog.dictionary.com/word-fact-toward-vs-towards/).

> Does your organization have any sympathies **towards** (such and such ideologies)?

You'll find many examples for such usage on [Google](https://google.com/#q=%22sympathies+towards%22)

Comment: I think you're right.  Seems to be most conventional.